# PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground in Swift - Missing argument for parameter 'target' call

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am implementing the login function for Parse written in Swift. I am getting an error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'target' call

It doesn't seem like I"m missing any parameters though - I'm following the declaration in PFUser.h.

Here is my code:

```
//Declarations
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let userEmail = usernameTextField.text
    let userPassword = passwordTextField.text

    //Check that both fields are filled
    if usernameTextField != "" && passwordTextField != "" {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmail, password: userPassword) {
            (user: PFUser, error: NSError) -> Void in {
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have extra curly braces and the username and password checks are wrong. Try below code (copy & paste please) it works:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let userEmail = usernameTextField.text
    let userPassword = passwordTextField.text

    if !userEmail.isEmpty && !userPassword.isEmpty {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmail, password: userPassword) { (user, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("succesful")
            } else {
                println("error: \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

EDIT: 
`PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text as String!, password: password.text as String!){
                (loggedInuser: PFUser?, signupError: NSError?) -> Void in`

EDIT 2: Okay sorry I had to look at my code but here's what I have working for me.

Text fields declared as

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameText: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
```

Log user in

```
PFUser.logInUserInBackground(usernameText.text, password: passwordText.text) {(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in ....}
```

Comment: I removed the ?, new error: "Cannot invoke 'logInWithUsernameInBackground' with an argument list type '(String!, password: String!, (PFUser, NSError) -> Void)'"

Comment: How are your username and password variables declared?

Comment: Can you please edit your original question and post the relevant code?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect new solution.

Comment: The problem remains the same. I'm missing argument for parameter 'target'